# Footer Issues : Can't Keep it Down

Tags: html, css, footer

I have been trying for 2 hours to get my footer to stay at the bottom. 
I have been trying "Matthew James Taylors" technique, but no luck.

Anyone see what I am missing or doing wrong?

Here is a Live Example : http://glustik.com/essex/index.html

Any help would be GREAT!

I would attached the CSS Code with the { } but it always breaks for me.

Comment: Not an answer, but just so you are aware: `id` values are supposed to be unique (no two should be the same on one page). Use class names if you need duplicate values.

Comment: Are you looking for a "sticky footer" (always at bottom of screen) or just trying to get the footer to be at the bottom of the container?

Comment: You should definitely fix the problem pointed out by Wesley.  Duplicate id's lead to unpredictable behavior and cross-browser issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like the CSS to fix this will still be problematic, I would be tempted to rewrite the whole thing: HTML markup and CSS, otherwise I suspect there will be more trouble down the road.

Here are some things that are most likely giving you trouble:

- Duplicate `id` values (as mentioned)
- Unnecessary `absolute` positioning
- Hard-coded height values on several divs
- Unnecessary use of "clearfix" divs
- Overuse of negative margins to compensate for padding on other elements (always problematic)
- Minor but relevant: use of classes like `floatRight`, just as bad as using inline styles.

I think in general, instead of trying to control the positioning and height of everything - just let the normal content flow dictate it. Naturally, the last element in your markup (footer) should be on the bottom without all these over-thought restrictions.

Best of luck!

**EDIT**: Apparently I've come off as unhelpful, so I felt I should add a direct response: For a quick fix, to simply get the footer on the bottom:

- Remove the height and bottom padding from `#mainBody`

(tested in FF4 and IE8). There will still be some padding issues within the footer, but that can be resolved in a number of ways depending on how you'd like to approach it. Once again, good luck with your project.

Comment: This answer is very useful and correct, but it doesn't really answer @Varazi's question....  No downvote, since it's great info, but it doesn't really present a solution, just lots of problems.

Comment: @rockerest: The problem is that as I started to come up with several solutions, I realized they were all hacks and required a fairly significant restructuring of the layout and CSS in order to avoid even more hacks in the future. There is a lot of crazy stuff going on in the CSS, and I didn't want to simply offer another band-aid when surgery was appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You have the footer positioned absolutely in `#container`, which is positioned relatively. therefore, its being positioned at the bottom of `#container`.

try moving it out of `#container`, or remove the relative positioning from #container

Answer (score 1):

Because all of the content inside your main container (`#mainBody`) is floated, the container's only way to determine it's height is via the "height" property, which is set to `100px;`.  The footer is correctly rendering right below the 100 pixel height of the main container.

You have three options:

1. you can either properly clear your main container so that its height is dynamic based on its content using a clearfix like [this](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)
2. or you can set the height of the main container to something larger.  I changed it to 700px and the footer rendered **well** below the main body.
3. or you can remove the `height` altogether, which will probably be the best solution in the long-run. Thanks to @Gaby aka G. Petrioli for pointing this out.

Comment: @Gaby +1 to your comment :)  There's not really a clear reason for that height to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing this a long time and have never heard of this method.  That doesn't make it bad, but the currently accepted version in my circles comes from Ryan Fait (http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/)

If you load this up in Chrome and disable the position:relative from the container it does properly glue the footer to the bottom of the page.  That signals a problem to me, because it's contrary to what the tutorial says.  Regardless, it accomplishes your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You should take at least a look at Compass. It makes CSS so much easier. For your particular question, take a look at:

http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/layout/sticky_footer/

Comment: I'm not so sure he wants a sticky footer, I believe he just wants the footer to be at the bottom of his layout container.

Answer (score -1):

Make the following changes and it rendered fine in Chrome for me:

- remove `bottom:0;` from `#footer`
- change `padding-bottom:167px;` in `#mainBody` to the desired location (I used `455px` and it looked pretty good)